# Automatically import a local CSV file with Javascript or Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, csv, local

My client wants a website that includes importing CSV data WITHOUT it being hosted on a server. The idea is so that their sales people can demonstrate their products without having web access or hosting set up on their PCs. They will also be able to update the data by exporting a new CSV file from the original Excel document, without any knowledge of HTML or Javascript.

I've found quite a few solutions online - like Papa Parse (http://papaparse.com/) but all of them require the user to select a file using `<input type="file" />`. As an example, the following script, using Papa Parse, works perfectly well:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Test CSV</title>
</head>
<body>
  <input type="file" />
</body>
<script src="js/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.parse.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript">
  $('input').change(function(e) {
    $('input[type=file]').parse({
        complete: function(data) {
            console.log('Parse results:', data.results);
        }
    });
});
</script>
</html>
```

My problem is that I need to be able to hard-code the CSV file's location so that, when the web page is opened, the data is automatically displayed, without any further interaction by the user. Is this possible? Or have I overlooked something really basic?

Comment: The user will at some point need to specify a file location. Is it an issue if the user has to select the file once?

Comment: afaik browser security requires the user to select the file every time. can you point to a file on a server running in localhost? can you store the file in memory with sessionStorage and then parse the text using $.parse(csvString)?

Comment: The file MUST be read automatically. Also, there will be no access to localhost.

Comment: eg. create a button that says "load file", load the file from sessionStorage into a text area so the user can see it, then parse the value of the loaded data from a textarea using `$.parse(text)`

Comment: Unfortunately I can't have a button that requires user input, ever. I may have to find a different solution...

Comment: what about storing the file in a textarea?

Comment: im not sure I understand. If the sales people are giving the demo from their machine, you could set this up once before they give the demo, while on the plane, in the hotel the night before, before they leave for the presentation, etc...

Comment: Clients! Had a meeting yesterday and they've changed their minds - now it's to be hosted on their intranet so this whole exercise has been a waste of time. Aaaaargh! But thanks for the suggestions, anyway.

Comment: I just added (to the top) another idea I came up with when I got home. Which is pretty awesome. I've been using this for templates for quite some time but had never thought of storing CSV data.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hardcode the values inside a script tag of a non-javascript `type` such as `text/csv` then extract it with innerHTML or `$("#unparsed").html()`

```
<script type="text/csv" id="unparsed">
    url,title,size
    images/address-book.png?1354486198, Address Book, 1904 KB
    images/front-row.png?1354486198, Front Row, 401 KB
    images/google-pokemon.png?1354486198, Google Pokémon, 12875 KB
    ...
</script>

$(function parseData(){
    $("#file").hide();
    var data = $("#unparsed").html();
    var parsed = $.parse(data);
    $("#parsed").val(JSON.stringify(parsed));
})
```

http://jsbin.com/racanefi/10/edit

Hardcode the values inside a textarea.

```
$(function parseData(){
  $("#file").hide();
  var data = $("#unparsed").val();
  var parsed = $.parse(data);
  $("#parsed").val(JSON.stringify(parsed));
})
```

http://jsbin.com/racanefi/8/edit

OR

Store the value in localStorage.

```
var storage = localStorage;
var key = 'unparsed_text_file';

function getFile(){
$("#file").change(function(){
  var file = $(this).eq(0)[0].files[0],
    reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(e) {
      var text = reader.result;
      storage.setItem(key,text);
      parseData();
    };
    reader.readAsText(file);
});
}

function parseData(){
  $("#file").hide();
  var data = storage.getItem(key);
  var parsed = $.parse(data);
  $("#unparsed").val(data);
  $("#parsed").val(JSON.stringify(parsed));
}

if(storage.getItem(key))
  parseData();
else
  getFile();
```

http://jsbin.com/racanefi/6/edit

**Browser Compatibility:**
http://caniuse.com/namevalue-storage

This is a rough draft, you should probably QA it well before implementing it.

*edit: I had it backwards sessionStorage is temporary across sessions. localStorage is more permanent. I created a variable that lets you assign your storage to a `var storage`*

Answer (score 3):

PapaParse is good quality stuff but for completion sake here's how it's done with [jquery-csv](https://github.com/evanplaice/jquery-csv)

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>Demo - CSV-to-Table</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="inputs" class="clearfix">
    <input type="file" id="files" name="files[]" multiple />
  </div>
  <hr />
  <output id="list">
  </output>
  <hr />
  <table id="contents" style="width:100%; height:400px;" border>
  </table>

  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://evanplaice.github.io/jquery-csv/src/jquery.csv.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      if(isAPIAvailable()) {
        $('#files').bind('change', handleFileSelect);
      }
    });

    function isAPIAvailable() {
      // Check for the various File API support.
      if (window.File && window.FileReader && window.FileList && window.Blob) {
        // Great success! All the File APIs are supported.
        return true;
      } else {
        // source: File API availability - http://caniuse.com/#feat=fileapi
        // source: <output> availability - http://html5doctor.com/the-output-element/
        document.writeln('The HTML5 APIs used in this form are only available in the following browsers:<br />');
        // 6.0 File API & 13.0 <output>
        document.writeln(' - Google Chrome: 13.0 or later<br />');
        // 3.6 File API & 6.0 <output>
        document.writeln(' - Mozilla Firefox: 6.0 or later<br />');
        // 10.0 File API & 10.0 <output>
        document.writeln(' - Internet Explorer: Not supported (partial support expected in 10.0)<br />');
        // ? File API & 5.1 <output>
        document.writeln(' - Safari: Not supported<br />');
        // ? File API & 9.2 <output>
        document.writeln(' - Opera: Not supported');
        return false;
      }
    }

    function handleFileSelect(evt) {
      var files = evt.target.files; // FileList object
      var file = files[0];

      // read the file metadata
      var output = ''
          output += '<span style="font-weight:bold;">' + escape(file.name) + '</span><br />\n';
          output += ' - FileType: ' + (file.type || 'n/a') + '<br />\n';
          output += ' - FileSize: ' + file.size + ' bytes<br />\n';
          output += ' - LastModified: ' + (file.lastModifiedDate ? file.lastModifiedDate.toLocaleDateString() : 'n/a') + '<br />\n';

      // read the file contents
      printTable(file);

      // post the results
      $('#list').append(output);
    }

    function printTable(file) {
      var reader = new FileReader();
      reader.readAsText(file);
      reader.onload = function(event){
        var csv = event.target.result;
        var data = $.csv.toArrays(csv);
        var html = '';
        for(var row in data) {
          html += '<tr>\r\n';
          for(var item in data[row]) {
            html += '<td>' + data[row][item] + '</td>\r\n';
          }
          html += '</tr>\r\n';
        }
        $('#contents').html(html);
      };
      reader.onerror = function(){ alert('Unable to read ' + file.fileName); };
    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Feature detection (ie which browsers won't work) is built-in, and the file has to be loaded via a file dialog because the sandbox protections block scripts from accessing the filesystem directly.

*Disclaimer: I'm the author of jquery-csv.*