# Autoload a filename in input file=""

Tags: jquery, html

Instead of showing an input button to select a filename is there a way to hardwire a specific filename in my root folder that gets loaded automagically? (Not looking for the user to select a filename) Modifying evanplaice's excellent CSV to JS code for 2d arrays...so I'd like to stick to using input... I see there are methods to hide the button using a CSS style opacity of 0...thanks in advance, Chris.

The filename I'd like to force/hardwire is "SocialabSchedule2clean.csv"

```
<input type="file" id="files" name="files[]"  />
var files = evt.target.files; // FileList object 
    var file = files[0]; 

function handleFileSelect(evt) {
   var files = evt.target.files; // FileList object 
    var file = files[0]; 

  // read the file contents
  printTable(file);

  // post the results
  $('#list').append(output);
}   

function printTable(file) {
  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.readAsText(file);
  reader.onload = function(event){
    var csv = event.target.result;
    var data = $.csv.toArrays(csv);
    var html = '';
    for(var row in data) {
      html += '<tr>\r\n';
      for(var item in data[row]) {
        html += '<td>' + data[row][item] + '</td>\r\n';
      }
      html += '</tr>\r\n';
    }
    $('#contents').html(html);
  };
  reader.onerror = function(){ alert('Unable to read ' + file.fileName); };
}
```

Comment: Automatically loading a file without user interaction would allow any website to upload the entire contents of your hard drive to their servers, without you even noticing. That wouldn't be so good.

Comment: Thanks Siguza, but I would hardwire the location and name of the file to be loaded on my own page/server.

Comment: In that case, I believe you want an [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest), and not a file input field.

Comment: Thanks Siguza, I'll check that out, do you have familiarity with this?

Comment: For others I'm finding these threads regarding autoloading a file:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35804074/jquery-csv-accessing-local-file

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24172045/automatically-import-a-local-csv-file-with-javascript-or-jquery/24172885#24172885

Comment: Thank you Jan Jouke Tjalsma.  I'll try that now

Comment: For other newbies here is a working sample:http://www.inversemedia.com/socialab/Test3/CTfileloader9.html  Note that the return value of status only shows success, if file specified is not found it's not showing failure and seems to hang...

Answer (score 0):

If you need to load a file from your webserver you can use a request like @siguza suggested.

```
$.get("path/to/SocialabSchedule2clean.csv", function(response, status){
    if(status=="succes"){
        var data = $.csv.toArrays(response); 
        var html = ''; 
        for(var row in data) { 
            html += '<tr>\r\n';
            for(var item in data[row]) { 
            html += '<td>' + data[row][item] + '</td>\r\n'; } 
            html += '</tr>\r\n'; 
        } 
        $('#contents').html(html);
    }
});
```

Comment: This works, thank you Jan Jouke Tjalsma and @Siguza.

Comment: @InverseMedia You're welcome! If this or another answer fixed your problem please click the checkmark to accept that answer.

Comment: I tried but this is the response: Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score.

Comment: Ah yes. There is the up arrow but that is upvoting. There should be a checkmark for accepting as well. You can see here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235

P.S. welcome on Stackoverflow!

Answer (score 0):

THIS WORKS EXCEPT FOR STATUS FAILURE WITH MISSING FILENAME

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>Demo - CSV-to-Table</title>
</head>

<body>

<table id="contents" style="width:100%; height:400px;" border>
</table>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.inversemedia.com/socialab/Test3/jquery.csv.js">        </script>
<script>

 document.getElementById("contents").innerHTML = "STARTING UP";

    $.get("http://www.inversemedia.com/socialab/Test3/SocialabSchedule3clean.csv", function(response, status){  
 alert("Status: " + status);
 if(status=="success"){
    var data = $.csv.toArrays(response); 
    var html = ''; 
    for(var row in data) { 
        html += '<tr>\r\n';
        for(var item in data[row]) { 
        html += '<td>' + data[row][item] + '</td>\r\n'; } 
        html += '</tr>\r\n'; 
    } 
    $('#contents').html(html);
}
else
document.getElementById("contents").innerHTML = "FAILURE"; 
});

</script>
</body>
</html>
```